# Lleave a selected image on each step

Tags: jquery

Currently I managed to do for everyone image to be marked.
I need only one image must be selected in each step if it selected the other image should be deselected.

```
$("img").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e1k97t4e/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have only one selected item in a `.container` so

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hover").closest('.container').find('img.hover').not(this).removeClass('hover');
  });
});
```

```css
.container-image {
  display: inline-block;
}
.hover {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p>step 1</p>
  <div class="container-image">
    <img src="http://www.interstar.com/img/1_icon.png">
  </div>
  <div class="container-image">
    <img src="http://www.interstar.com/img/2_icon.png">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>step 2</p>
  <div class="container-image">
    <img src="http://www.interstar.com/img/1_icon.png">
  </div>
  <div class="container-image">
    <img src="http://www.interstar.com/img/2_icon.png">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>step 3</p>
  <div class="container-image">
    <img src="http://www.interstar.com/img/1_icon.png">
  </div>
  <div class="container-image">
    <img src="http://www.interstar.com/img/2_icon.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
$("img").click(function() {
      $("img").not(this).removeClass("hover");
      $(this).toggleClass("hover");
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/28197q4e/)**